# What is forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I want to ask an question about the objective C. What is `"content-type"` in the `NSMutableURLRequest`? Is it related to the header field as I see the `forHTTPHeaderField`?

Also, what is the different between the following statement?

```
// statement 1
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// statement 2
[request setValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-type` is known as a *MIME type* that indicates what kind of data an HTTP response contains.

Here is more information about MIME types and some examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

For a full list of official MIME types approved by the IANA, take a look here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/

To answer your other question:

- Statement 1 is a MIME type for a response to a web form that has been filled in.
- Statement 2 is the MIME type for a standard HTML page which has a characterset of UTF-8 (basically, international support versus standard ASCII or something else).

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I would like to ask about the '&'. Is it are ASCII or non-ASCII? And what mean of 'filled in' in statement 1? Thank you.