# how to sync or upload the image and multiple data on to the remote server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying so much to upload the image and video  with other data But not success how can I do that .
My app is like that i have take data from the sqlite database and I want to that data which i am gettig from the sqlite .And for image have only the url .
Before that I done sync with  the normal data .But image and video i have no idea how can do that .
For sync or uploading data i done code 
Like this

```
-(void)sendRequest
{

    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    //Create the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Set the required date format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    //Get the string date
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token=%@&LocationID=%@&JourneyID=%@&Altitude=%@&Longitude=%@&Latitude=%@&Speed=%@&Accuracy=%@&LocationDate=%@&LastSyncDate=%@",tokenapi,Location_ID,Journey_jlID,Altitude_jl,Longitude_jl,Latitude_jl,Speed_jl,Accuracy_jl,LocationDate_jl,str];
    NSLog(@"%@",post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
    postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease]; 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com?RequestType=UserJourneyLocation&Command=NEW"]]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);

    }


}
```

**But how can send the multiple data to server  with image and video data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this to post the data on server.

```
NSError *error = nil; 

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:POST_URL]; 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

NSString *boundary = @"-------------------a9d8vyb89089dy70"; 

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]; 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  

[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

[postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"contentID\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

[postBody appendData:[@"127_8_1315579702522" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

......

// Pass here your other Paramater as like Content ID

......

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"image_file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"image.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:ImageDataPost];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSData *shoutData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: what's this [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: Please see this link for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202838/what-is-forhttpheaderfieldcontent-type-in-objective-c

Comment: it is very useful in posting image